# Showing $\sin(nx)$ is a complete orthonormal system

Tags: functional-analysis, orthonormal

I want to prove that the system $\sin(nx)$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$ is complete in $L_2[0,\pi]$, so what I do is assume that:

$$\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(kx)dx=0,\quad k=1,2,\cdots$$

An define an odd function:

$$\overline{f}(x) =\left\{ \begin{matrix}f(x),&0\leq x\lt \pi\\ -f(-x),& -\pi \leq x \lt 0\end{matrix} \right.$$

And we have that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \overline{f}(x) dx = 0, \int_{-\pi}^\pi \overline{f}(x)\cos(nx) dx=0 $

Since $\overline{f}$ is an odd function we have:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \overline{f}(x)\sin(nx) dx =2 \int_{-\pi}^\pi \overline{f}(x)\sin(nx)dx=2\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)d=0$$

Where the last bit equals zero by assumption.

---

Now this is the bit I don't understand, I am meant to conclude:

"**Thus, since the system**$\{1,\sin(nx),\cos(nx)\}_n$ **is complete in** $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, **we obtain** $\overline{f}(x)=0$ **in** $[-\pi,\pi]$ and hence $f(x) = 0$ in $[0,\pi]$"

Comment: Hint: $\sin nx = \frac1{2i}\left(e^{inx}-e^{-inx}\right)$.

Comment: Um... What do you not understand? Now your $\bar f$ is orthnormal to $1, \cos$ and $\sin $ function, so it has to be zero.

Comment: @JohnMa So now $\{\sin(nx)\}_n$ is complete in $L^2[0,\pi]$ since the only function orthogonal to it, is the zero function?

Comment: You have moved all the calculations to $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ already. That $\overline f$ is orthonormal to the constant functions and all other $\cos, \sin$ functions. So $\overline f = 0$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Restricting back to $[0,\pi]$, it means $f = 0$ on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\bar{f}$ is essentially odd (except possibly at $x=0$) we have
$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \bar{f}(x) \cos(nx) dx = 0$ for all $n$ (including $n=0$).

Hence $\bar{f}$ is orthogonal to $x \mapsto \sin (nx)$, $x \mapsto \cos (nx)$ for all
$n$, completeness implies that $\bar{f}(x) = 0$ ae.

Comment: Two questions, 1) does your name refer to a diving helmet? 2) What is a good resource that covers this topic?

Comment: 1) A joking reference to my concern about privacy; the aliens can't read my brain waves while wearing a copper hat :-). 2) Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis" is a reasonable resource.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: @copper.hat Are you sure about that reference? I don't recall anything in Rudin about preventing aliens from reading brain waves.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It is part of the Rudin Code Puzzle :-).

Comment: This proof uses the fact that in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ a set of $\{1, \cos{nx}, \sin{nx} \}$ is complete orthogonal. Is there a way to prove it without that fact?