# Is $\cos(n x)$ a complete orthonormal system for $L^2(0,\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, orthonormal

This question says

[Showing $\sin(nx)$ is a complete orthonormal system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518492/showing-sinnx-is-a-complete-orthonormal-system)

Merely $\sin(nx)$ forms a complete orthonormal system for $L^2(0,\pi)$, which I thought was interesting. Can the same be said for $\cos(nx)$? I tried to follow the above question and tried to make up an even function but somehow did not work out.

Comment: What didn't work out when you set $\overline{f}(x) = f(\lvert x\rvert)$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: Nothing didn't work out...I should have come up with that transformation...Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A,B$ are real constants that are not both $0$, and suppose $C,D$ are also real constants that are not both $0$. Consider the system
$$
                       y''+\lambda y = 0 \\
                       Ay(0)+By'(0) = 0,\\ Cy(\pi)+Dy'(\pi)=0.
$$
Note that $y=0$ is always a solution of the above problem. There are non-trivial solutions of the above equation only for a discrete sequence of real $\lambda$ values
$$
                   \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3 < \cdots.
$$
For each such $\lambda_k$, the non-trivial solution $y_k(x)$ is unique up to a non-zero multiplicative constant, and the solutions $\{ y_k \}$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$.

**Sine Example**: Let $A=1,B=0$, $C=1,D=0$. The non-trivial solutions of
$$
                  y''+\lambda y =0 \\
                   y(0)=0,\;\; y(\pi)=0,
$$
are $\sin(nx)$, corresponding to $\lambda_n=n^2$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. These form an orthogonal basis of $L^2$.

**Cosine Example:** Let $A=0,B=1,C=0,D=1$. The non-trivial solutions of
$$
           y''+\lambda y = 0, \\
           y'(0)=0,\; y'(\pi)=0,
$$
are $\cos(nx)$, corresponding to $\lambda_n=n^2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. These form an orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$.

**Half-Angle Sine Example:** Let $A=0,B=1, C=1,D=0$. The non-trivial solutions of
$$
           y''+\lambda y = 0, \\
           y(0)=0,\; y'(\pi) =0,
$$
are $\sin((n+1/2)x)$, corresponding to $\lambda_n = (n+1/2)^2$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. These functions must also form an orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$.

**General Examples** There are general cases where the $\sqrt{\lambda_n}$ terms are not evenly spaced, and are solutions of a transcendental equation. The corresponding solutions must still form a complete orthogonal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$. These cases cannot be handled directly from the ordinary Fourier basis.

Comment: Thanks, could I ask some references?

Comment: @user412313 : The classical reference is Chapter 1 of E. C. Titchmarsh, *Eigenfunction Expansions Associted with Second Order Differential Equations*

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Your answers are really weird, I don't get what you want to say. See mine

Comment: @user1952009 : I'm responding to the OP by stating a far more general result that gives the completeness of a large class of trigonometric functions, ones where the arguments are not simple multiples of a base argument, and are not necessarily evenly spaced either.

Comment: You should stop with those answers, assuming the spectral theorem, without even mentioning it.

Comment: @user1952009 : The Spectral Theorem evolved from studying these problems, not the other way around. These problems came at least a century before the Spectral Theorem. In fact, Spectral Theory evolved out of studying this class of problems, and, in particular, out of studying the trigonometric functions with arguments that are solutions of a transcendental equation, a topic first studied by Fourier in his early 19th century Treatise on Heat Conduction.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Yes but no, your answers are not adapted. The question is not "how the Fourier series are useful in the theory of differential equations" as well in the other question

Comment: @user1952009 : It can be "how theory of differential equations can be useful to general Fourier expansions." And that's what this falls under. You seem to be rather antagonistic. Have I offended you in some way?

Comment: No, I'm trying to be constructive. If you really think this is useful, then write the excepted/adapted answer first

Comment: @user1952009 : The first example of the general case stated is the subject of the question. The other examples are there for further understanding of the general case. You don't have to like my answer. I like my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Check the orthonormality of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cup \{\frac{\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi /2}}\}_{n \ge 1}$$

and for completeness note that if $f\in L^2(0,\pi)$ then $g(x) = f(x)1_{x > 0}+ f(-x)1_{x < 0}$ is in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, so it has a Fourier series

$$g(x) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx)+b_n \sin(nx)$$

(the series converges in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and hence in $L^2(0,\pi)$)

finally $b_n=0$ since $g$ is even