# How can $\sin(n \pi x)$ be a complete ONB of $L^2([0,1])$ when $-\Delta$ is positive on them

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

As done in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518492/showing-sinnx-is-a-complete-orthonormal-system?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) one can prove that $\sin(n\pi \cdot), n \ge 1$ is a orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,1])$.

We also have that $(-\Delta)( \sin(n\pi\cdot) )= (n\pi)^2 \sin(n\pi \cdot)$, which means that we can diagonalize $-\Delta$ w.r.t. $\sin(n \pi x)$ and have only positive eigenvalues.

From this I now conclude that $-\Delta$ is strictly positive on $L^2([0,1])$. This is a contradiction to the constants and the linear functions being in the kernel of $-\Delta$ and also in $L^2([0,1])$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator domain comes with endpoint conditions $f(0)=f(1)=0$. That eliminates constants from being in the domain of the operator, unless those constants are $0$. If you choose endpoint conditions $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, then you end up with a new basis of eigenfunctions $\{1,\cos(\pi x),\cos(2\pi x),\cdots\}$.

Comment: How do you specify endpoint conditions in $L^2$?

Comment: @fubal The domain consists of twice absolutely continuous functions $f$ with $f''\in L^2$. That domain allows endpoint conditions, and the endpoint functionals $f(0),f(1),f'(0),f'(1)$ are continuous functions from the graph of $-\Delta$ to the scalars. Without endpoint conditions $-\Delta$ is not selfadjoint or even symmetric.

Comment: So what you say is that the domain of the operator is basically the sobolev space $H^2$ and that by either specifying $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ or $f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$ I end up with different subspaces of $H^2$ on which $-\Delta$ is selfadjoint? Also, isn't selfadjoint == symmetric?

Comment: @fubal For unbounded operators, selfadjoint is not the same as symmetric. The interesting part about this operator is that the domain with $f(0)=f(1)=0$ is a dense subspace that excludes every function in another complete orthonormal basis--namely those functions with $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a contradiction if $-\Delta$ were a *bounded* operator, but it's not (it's not even defined on all of $L^2([0,1])$.).

Write out the proof that it's a contradiction in detail, and you'll see there's a point where you use the non-fact that the operator is continuous.

Comment: I use it when I apply it to an arbitrary $f \in L^2$ which I write as coefficients and then pull the limit outside of the operator, right? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> From this I now conclude that $-\Delta$ is strictly positive on $L^2([0,1])$.

This is not true, because the representation of some element with respect to the mentioned ONB and the operator $-\Delta$ do not commute, because $-\Delta$ is not continuous operator!

As an example, let $f= 1_{[0,1]}$ be the indicator function of $[0,1]$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi nx) \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1-(-1)^n}{\pi n}.
\end{equation}
Thus
$$1_{[0,1]}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^n}{\pi n} \sin(\pi nx)$$
in $L^2$-sense. Now, you cannot apply the operator 'coordinatewise'! The resulting sum is not convergent.