# Is $\textrm{span}\{\sin(nx): n \in \mathbb N\}$ a sub-algebra of $C([0,\pi])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

I'm working on a proof that $B=\{\sin(nx):n \in \mathbb N\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2([0,\pi])$ and my missing link is that the sub-algebra of $C([0,\pi])$ generated by $B$ is its span. I've shown it is true for the cosine basis since $$\cos(a)\cos(b)=\frac {\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)} 2, $$ but the equivalent formula for $\sin(b)\sin(b)$ also involves cosines. Is the statement I want to prove really true? And if so how do I prove it?

Comment: Though it does not answer the algebra question, this question here might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518492/showing-sinnx-is-a-complete-orthonormal-system

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, but $\sin^2x$ cannot be a linear combination of finitely many $\sin nx$ on any interval (by analytic continuation this would be true in the plane and a simple integration shows this is impossible on $[0, 2\pi]$)

Comment: @Conrad I see, this does answer my question, but then I'm at a problem. I basically need to show the set of sines is a complete orthogonal set by showing its span is dense in $L^2[(0,\pi)]$, but I only know that the algebra generated by this set of sines is dense. So how do I proceed from here?

Comment: the way I would do it is to use the well known (and easy to prove) density of the trigonometric system (both $\sin, \cos$) in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and the fact that any function in $L^2([0,\pi])$ has a unique odd extension to $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, while for any odd function there, its expansion in the trigonometric basis is only given by $\sin$ terms; note that the $\sin nx$ terms do not approximate uniformly all the functions in $C([0,\pi])$ but only those that are zero at the two ends, so the fact that they actually form a basis in $L^2$ is a fairly subtle fact

Comment: On the other hand, all the continuous functions in $[-\pi, \pi]$ that agree at the ends (so they represent continuous functions on the unit circle or equivalently extend continuously to the real line by periodicity) are representable uniformly by trigonometric polynomials (the Feijer polynomials ie average of the Fourier ones will do)

Comment: @Conrad I see, that worked quite well for me, thanks.

Comment: happy to be of help